# How to login to aws using IAM user id and password?

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a desktop client through which we can login to https://(aws account id/ account alias).signin.aws.amazon.com/console  using IAM user id , password and account name.

We have JavaMail API to login into gmail account. ( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm )

Similarly , we have RestFB api to login into facebook account.

Do we have similar type of API for aws? If not, is there any other way to achieve the same behavior most preferably in java but python is also fine.

Comment: In the interest of clarity, once you log in, what kinds of operations on AWS do you plan for your desktop client to actually do?

Comment: I am trying to have a cloud based backend similar to directory services so that I can login from anywhere outside the cloud, using any client.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I do not understand your question correctly, what you are attempting is not supported.  The IAM username and password for an account can only be used to manually log in to the console.

> Q: Is there an authentication API to verify user logins?
>
> No. There is no programmatic way to verify user logins.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#login_anchor

Answer (score 1):

https://(aws account id/ account alias).signin.aws.amazon.com/console is an customized sign-in page url.

username/password is used when we manually log in to the console.

If you want to make programmatic calls, then you should create an access/secret keys for an IAM user, and use them to create an client to access respective AWS resource.

Answer (score 0):

AWS implement SAML for federated access. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-saml.html

Comment: SAML required local directory like active directory . We don't want to used that or any server in cloud.

Comment: not necessarily. in the diagram you need to implement steps 2,3,4. you can use things like OpenSAML to build the SAML assertion: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home